# 時間毎にアクセスできるWebサイトを制御したい

Tags: windows, network, dns, windows-server

ざっくりした質問で恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

こういうのはどう？とアイデアを頂ければ幸いです。
学校のネットワークで、各教室に30台ずつPCがあり、10教室あります。
これを、教室毎に随時学生がwebブラウザでアクセスできるサイトを制限したいです。

たとえば

- 授業中は Facebook, YouTube へはアクセスできなくする。
- 休憩時間は左記サイトのアクセスも許可する。
- テストを行うクラスについては、カンニング防止のためテスト用のWebサイト以外はアクセスできなくする。

ということをしたいです。

いずれもクライアントはWindows10 Enterpriseをインストールしています。
オンプレミスのWindows Server2016を使って、AcriveDirectory,DNS,DHCPでクライアント管理しています。
VLANは現在は使っていませんが利用可能です。
(10教室全部で同じネットワークにしていますが、VLANで教室毎のネットワークにすること可能です。）
パブリックネットワークにつながるルーターは、Yamaha RTX1210

私の考えた案としては、

- 各教室にproxyサーバーを立ててそこで制御する。
- 可能かどうかはわかりませんが、構内DNSサーバーに制限を設けてアクセスできなくする。
- ルーターのIPフィルタで条件設定を設ける。

あまり費用は使えないのですが、もし、他にもっと簡単な方法があるよというのがあれば教えて頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 2. は DNS 機構を知っている生徒には突破されますし 1. か 3. でしょう。教室ごとに時間を変更する必然があるか否か、この管理をいつ誰が行うのかで解は変わってきそうです。

Comment: 微妙なラインかもしれないですが、「こういうアイデアはどう？」だととめどなく回答が集まってしまいなかなかスタックオーバーフロー向けの質問（というよりアンケートかな？）ではないかもしれないですね。

Comment: あまり費用は使えないといいつつも各教室にプロキシサーバーを立てるぐらいの費用は出せるという感じですかね？コスト感ももっと明確にしたほうがいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにDNSの機構を突破されるのは時間の問題ですね。費用については１０万ぐらいが限度かと思いますが、きちんと設計できれば５０万ぐらいまでは出るかもしれません（交渉次第）　proxyについてはいま空いてるPCが10台ぐらいあるので、それにproxyサーバーソフトウエアのsquid入れて試してみる事は可能です。設計、製造、運用はすべて私が行います。ネットワークエンジニア、プログラマー両方で２５年ぐらいの実績がありますので多少のことはgoogleに頼りつつ自分でできるかと思っています。

Comment: >教室ごとに時間を変更する必然があるか否か、この管理をいつ誰が行うのかで解は変わってきそうです。
これは、ある程度運用方法が固まりテストも完了した時点で、それをITの知識がない教師でもできるようにスクリプトなりを作成してボタン一つで切り替えられるようにしたいと考えています。

Answer (score 0):

ルータでは難しいですが、

- プロキシサーバ
- Webフィルタ
- FW(UTM)

などの製品であればスケジュール制御を組み込むことができるものがあります。